# Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownError GC overhead limit exceeded in R 10.12.1

Tags: r, csv, neo4j, r-neo4j

Totally new to neo4j, I was running the csv file when this issue occurred, how can I fix this? thanks so much!!

```
library("RNeo4j")
library("curl")

graph <- startGraph("http://localhost:7474/db/data", username = "neo4j", password = "")
clear(graph, input = F)

query <- "LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM {csv} AS row CREATE (n:flights {year: row.year, month: row.mo, dep_time: row.dep_time, arr_time: row.arr_time, carrier: row.carrier, tailnum: row.tailnum, flight: row.flight, origin: row.origin, dest: row.dest, air_time: row.air_time, distance: row.distance, hour: row.hour, minute: row.minute })

cypher(graph, query, csv = "file:///flights1/flights.csv")
```

> Error: Client error: (400) Bad Request
>   Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownError
>   GC overhead limit exceeded

Comment: Can you provide the rest of your code?

Comment: @DaveCooper yes! Thanks for the kind suggestion, I just added the full statement

Comment: Does it fail just for that CSV file or any others you've tried?